# How to Implement PushNotifications in Phonegap using PushWoosh ?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, pushwoosh

I am trying to implement pushnotifications for phonegap using PushWoosh but I am actually not cleared with the documentation (Guide) , I am facing problem in the 4TH step unable to find the specified function in PushPlugin .....May I please know where to search for this function for modifications ?

> [image]

If anyone has implemented PushNotification using pushwoosh please let me know in the comments below.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421688/how-to-send-push-notification-using-phonegap-and-parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide is based on PushPlugin example:
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/tree/master/Example/www

In particular this file:
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/Example/www/index.html

Additionaly I would recommend using Pushwoosh Phonegap (Build) Plugin rather than Generic PushPlugin as Pushwoosh plugin provides much more features and flexibility!