# Phonegap and Parse.com Push Notifications android

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform

I am creating an app using html,jquery,php and phone gap and i want to send push notification using parse.I don't know how to do that. 
I have seen an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109548/phonegap-and-parse-com-push-notifications-ios) in SO But it is for ios. I need it for android. Will this work for android.
Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: Please check https://parse.com/questions/php-rest-example-of-targeted-push example..

Comment: thanx but how i will get TARGET_INSTALLATION_OBJECT_ID ....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer I've just posted, I've just got the Android Parse PNs working:

[How do I get Parse.com Push Notifications working in a Cordova/Phonegap Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038694/how-do-i-get-parse-com-push-notifications-working-in-a-cordova-phonegap-android/25038695#25038695)

That will help you get the app to recieve push notifications. To trigger them from PHP you'll need to use the REST API or a Third Party PHP library:

https://parse.com/docs/rest

https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library